# openerp 7 create method override

Tags: openerp-7

I am new OpenERP 7 programming. I have created a booking module that allows a guest to book more than one room. I want to be able to change the room status from **available** to **booked** when creating the new reservation. The solution to this kind of scenario seems to be overriding the **create** or **write** ORM methods for openERP.

I completely don't know how to incorporate this in my code. Below is part of my code.

```
class reservation(osv.osv):
    _columns = {
            'name': fields.char('Reservation No', required=True, select=True, readonly=True),
            'date_order':fields.datetime('Date Ordered', required=True, readonly=True),
            'reserved_rooms': fields.one2many('hotel.reservation.line','line_id', 'Reserved Rooms'),
            'state': fields.selection([('draft', 'Draft'),('confirmed','Confirmed'),('cancelled','Cancelled'),('done','Done')], 'State',readonly=True),
    }
reservation()

_defaults = {
        'name': lambda obj, cr, uid, context: obj.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid,'hotel.reservation'),
        'state': lambda *a: 'draft',
        'date_order': lambda *a: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
}
```

The reservation is created with the default state as draft. How and where in my code do i put and use the **create** or **write** method? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try following,

```
class reservation(osv.osv):
    _columns = {
            'name': fields.char('Reservation No', required=True, select=True, readonly=True),
            'date_order':fields.datetime('Date Ordered', required=True, readonly=True),
            'reserved_rooms': fields.one2many('hotel.reservation.line','line_id', 'Reserved Rooms'),
            'state': fields.selection([('draft', 'Draft'),('confirmed','Confirmed'),('cancelled','Cancelled'),('done','Done')], 'State',readonly=True),
     }

    _defaults = {
        'name': lambda obj, cr, uid, context: obj.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid,'hotel.reservation'),
        'state': lambda *a: 'draft',
        'date_order': lambda *a: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
     }

    def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
        ###Add your code here
        ####update status in vals
        return super(reservation,self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)

    def write(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None):
        ###Add your code here
        ####update status in vals
        ## you will get only those fields into the vals which are updated.
        return super(reservation,self).write(cr, uid, ids, vals, context=context)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer above but am aware of that. What i can't seem to get is how to access the dictionary of rooms(am assuming its a dictionary since its a one2many field) that were entered on the form. Once i know how to do that i will be able to loop through the values and change the status of the rooms.

Comment: If it's in create method then you should get `vals.get('reserved_rooms',False)` it returns list of ids or False not dictionary, or in write method you should write like this, 
`for obj in self.browse(cr,uid, ids, context=context):
    obj.reserved_rooms`, obj.reserved_rooms returns browsable objects not ids.